# Are C++ programs using exceptions required to have try/catch block in their main function?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer

If the exception is thrown by the C++ code but is not caught, it causes SIGABRT. Some systems just print "Abort", some other systems also print the contents of e.what().

The question is: Does the C++ standard say that try/catch block is required in the main function for the program to be considered a well behaved program, or does C++ just silently rely on the system to process this?

Answer (score 10):

As described in [C++17 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), in section 18.3.9 [except.handle]:

> If no matching handler is found, the function `std::terminate()` is called; whether or not the stack is unwound before this call to `std::terminate()` is implementation-defined.

So, the behavior of such program is not considered undefined, since standard defines, that `std::terminate` will be called.

Answer (score 8):

No, C++ standard doesn't require every exception to be caught. If the exception is not caught, the program terminates, and it is implementation-defined if stack unwinding is happening (it does with all the compilers I know). Further reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw